# Can the first word of an mySQL statement not be DELETE or UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently writing a page for querying the database instead of using the command line (it's just for practise on how PHP interacts with the database on the whole).

Right now, I'm trying to restrict deleting or updating data, i.e. no DELETE, DROP or UPDATE statement. After trimming all spaces (including \r and \s etc), will it be sufficient to just scan for the first word to determine what type of query it is? In other words, is it possible to write a DELETE, DROP or UPDATE query without having them as the first word after trimming spaces?

I'm currently using mysqli_query, so it's not possible to do multiple queries.

Edit 1: added relevant code @Tim.

```
$queryCheck = strtolower($query);
$queryCheck = preg_replace("/\s+/", "", $queryCheck);

if ( strpos($queryCheck, "deletefrom") === 0 ) {...}
else if ( strpos($queryCheck, "update") === 0) {...}
else if ( strpos($queryCheck, "create") === 0) {...}
else if ( strpos($queryCheck, "drop") === 0) {...}
```

Comment: If it's just to keep your database safe while testing I would instead restrict the privileges of your user on that database to SELECT. Not sure if there any other ways of sneaking in a changing query.

Comment: Oh, that is a solution as well!

As I'm the only one querying though, is it possible without having to change the privilleges?

Comment: No script will be as safe as what @PhilippGrassl says about. On topic, `mysqli_query` can process one query at a time so it _should_ begin with statement keyword, such as `DELETE` or `SELECT`.

Comment: Checking the first word wouldn't stop someone from sql injection. As in, `SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = 'a';DROP TABLE users;`

Comment: @ourmandave `mysqli_query` cannot process multi query. `mysqli_multi_query` has to be used for it.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: @Tim I added relevant parts of my code.

Answer (score 2):

Although evaluating user input as code is **never** a good idea, I can't think of a query that could be used to alter data if you are

1. Converting all whitespace (including line breaks) in to single spaces.
2. Checking the first word to see if it's `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `DROP`, `ALTER`, `TRUNCATE` or any other keyword that could be used to alter the data or table itself in some way

However, be careful of a query that looks like this:

```
--SELECT * FROM `table`
DROP table `table`
```

If you're not stripping newlines, this query would get executed, because although it doesn't start with `DROP` and it appears to be multiple queries, the first line is commented out.

---

After looking at your code, I would add this `if` statement:

```
if ( substr($queryCheck, 0, 6) != "select" && substr($queryCheck, 0, 6) != "insert" && substr($queryCheck, 0, 4) != "show" ) {
  die("You can only execute select, insert, or show queries!");
}
```

This checks to see if the first word is `select`, `insert`, or `show`. If it isn't the script stops executing. It is also a bit safer because instead of whitelisting all MySQL queries and then putting some on a blacklist, it starts with all functions on a blacklist, and puts some on a whitelist.

Comment: Beware that mysql has a PREPARE statement to prepare statements. I think you could send such a PREPARE to prepare and then execute a DELETE statement, with DELETE then NOT being the first word! See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/prepare.html

Comment: You're right, I know it really isn't a good idea as compared to Philipp's suggestion. But being able to check in code is more versatile than creating several users with different grants in mysql.

The strtolower is just to make sure the user can't enter something like "DroP table".

Comment: Also, `$query` is the actual query, `$queryCheck` is used only for the check.

Comment: Cool, your version is definitely less code. I'd also like to use SHOW so I'll add that to the list. Thanks @Tim! :)